# How do I turn logging off using log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, configuration-files

I am using a third-party library which has a log4j.xml configuration - what's the best way to turn off the logging?

Comment: Are you trying remove ALL logging or just from this third party library?

Comment: I'm trying to remove ALL logging. Everything!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think all that is required is to set the threshold parameter to OFF

```
<log4j:configuration threshold="OFF">
    <root>
        <priority value ="off" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="rolling-file" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 15):

Or directly from code:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().removeAllAppenders();
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on configuration. Try something like:

```
<log4j:configuration>
    <root>
        <priority value ="off" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="rolling-file" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Check [Log4jXmlFormat](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try setting the logging level to "Severe" if you only want to log game-breaking events.

Answer (score 0):

With log4j.xml the minimal solution looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration threshold="off">
</log4j:configuration>
```

Note that in `threshold="off"`, "off" must be in lower case.