# How to disable log4j in web applications (turn off WARN messages)

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, log4j, activemq-classic, slf4j

**In short:** How can I configure some Log4j logger in a third-party jar which is used in a web application so that it stops writing out warnings like

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

and prevents a clean shutdown throwing errors like

```
Exception in thread "InactivityMonitor WriteCheck" java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception in thread "InactivityMonitor ReadCheck" at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source) java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**The details:**

I am writing a Tomcat web application which shall use Apache ActiveMQ. Aside from *activemq-all-5.5.1.jar* I had to put the following libraries on the class path to get rid of classpath issues:

- log4j-1.2.15.jar
- slf4j-api-1.5.11.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11.jar

Now my application starts printing warnings like that one above. There is [a link on the Apache ActiveMQ web site](https://activemq.apache.org/log4j-warn-no-appenders-could-be-found-for-logger.html), but unfortunately it’s broken, and [Log4j wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/) is offline.

I tried to create a file named *log4j.xml* as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244487/how-do-i-turn-logging-off-using-log4j) and put it in the *WEB-INF/* directory (where I would expect it to belong) but I also tried to put it in the “default package” with my source code (i.e. *WEB-INF/classes/*). I also tried the same adding XML headers to the file as I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619160/sample-xml-configuration-for-log4j-have-a-main-java-application-and-want-to-w). None of them works in either location. I read elsewhere that one has to pass the location by passing the `-Dlog4j.configuration=` parameter to the JVM, but that cannot be used in web application context. A [Log4j for web application tutorial](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-initialize-log4j-in-a-web-application.html) shows how to configure it using *web.xml*, but that requires the library to contain a class which extends `HttpServlet`. I guess there isn’t such a class in Active MQ, and even if, how would I find it?

Perhaps I am barking up the totally wrong tree and I do not have to configure Log4j itself, but instead Slf4j which then will silently configure Log4j for me?

Which is the most simple way to cleanly swich off this logger as long as I don’t need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of these messages, create a file named `log4j.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration threshold="off">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="off" />
    </appender>
    <appender name="rolling-file" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="off" />
    </appender>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Drop the file in the “default package”. In an IDE, this usually is a folder called `/src`. In a web application design, this will map to `/WEB-INF/classes` during build.

Answer (score 1):

The way to get rid of this message is to set up your Log4J config correctly. Create a `log4j.properties` file and place it under `WEB-INF/classes` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3523730/263052).